# How to put 2 or 3 NeumannValue conditions?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I want to solve numerically the heat exchange of a fin in transient state and two-dimentional, here is my attempt but instead of put `DirichletCondition` on boundaries of $y$. I want to put Neumann Values. Can I do that?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
tf = 0.02;
A = 90 10^-2;
Tc = 10;
Tf = 5;
S1 = NDSolve[{A (D[T[t, x, y], x, x] + D[T[t, x, y], y, y]) - 
     D[T[t, x, y], t] == NeumannValue[100, x == 0.2], 
   DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == Tc, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == Tf, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == Tf, y == 0.05], T[0, x, y] == Tf},
   T, {t, 0, tf}, {x, 0, 0.2}, {y, 0, 0.05}]
G1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[T[tf, x, y] /. S1], {x, 0, 0.2}, {y, 0, 0.05}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Something like `NeumannValue[100, x == 0.2] +  NeumannValue[200, y == 0.]`?

Comment: Exactly!! That was so easy (It´s my first time using Mathematica), Thank you very much,  Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

`NeumannValue` type boundary conditions may overlap, while `DirichletCondition` may not overlap. So something like this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
tf = 0.02;
A = 90 10^-2;
Tc = 10;
Tf = 5;
S1 = NDSolve[{A (D[T[t, x, y], x, x] + D[T[t, x, y], y, y]) - 
      D[T[t, x, y], t] == 
     NeumannValue[100, x == 0.2] + 
      NeumannValue[100 T[t, x, y], x == 0.2 && y <= 0.025], 
    DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == Tc, x == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == Tf, y == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == Tf, y == 0.05], 
    T[0, x, y] == Tf}, T, {t, 0, tf}, {x, 0, 0.2}, {y, 0, 0.05}];
G1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[T[tf, x, y] /. S1], {x, 0, 0.2}, {y, 0, 0.05}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Note the kink at y==0.025. Probably it would be good if the mesh respected this discontinuity.